# Convert a6 flyer in printable leaflet on a4

Tags: printing, flyers

I would like to print a leaflet of flyer in a6 format. Therefore, I would like to convert it to a double-sided a4 document, that I can print double-sided, cut in half and fold. It is important, to get the order of the pages right. Is there an easy way to do it with LaTeX?

A possible document could look like this:

```
\documentclass[paper=a6]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
    page 1
    \newpage
    page 2
    \newpage
    page 3
    \newpage
    page 4
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this with two consecutive documents, called "Wrap1.tex" and "Wrap2.tex"

Wrap1.tex would look like this, where you have to insert the name of your document instead of "document.pdf":

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2.cm,bottom=2.cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1,4,1,4,2,3,2,3},signature=4,landscape]{document.pdf}
\end{document}
```

And Wrap2.tex would look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2.cm,bottom=2.cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1,4,3,2},signature=4, landscape]{Wrap1.pdf}
\end{document}
```

First, compile your document, then, in the same folder, Wrap1 and Wrap2 consecutively. That should do the job.

Cheers, Simon